# Display sub-collection in flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the data of a sub-collection named "Profile". I get it that we need to query it differently, and I tried it, but it is not working out for me. First, I displayed the information from the documents of the mother collection "mentors", using StreamBuilder. Then passed it's data to a Widget I created. Then on the Widget I created, I performed another streamBuilder query for the subcollection of each document of the Mother Collection "mentors".

This is the code I used to display the documents on "mentors" collection, and is working fine.

```
final mentors = Expanded(
  child: Container(
    height: 250,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: db_mentors,
        builder: (
          BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
        ) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "An Error Occured");
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Loading");
          }

          final data = snapshot.requireData;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.size,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              return mentorsWidget(
                "${data.docs[index]["uid"]}",
                "${data.docs[index]['name']}",
                "${data.docs[index]['specialty']}",
              );
            }),
          );
        }),
  ),
);
```

This here is the code I used to display the data from the subcollection of each document named "Profile". Which is also the widget I created.

```
Widget mentorsWidget(String uid, String name, String specialty) {
  return Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
    width: size.width,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 42, 134),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20))),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("mentors")
                .doc(uid)
                .collection("Profile")
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (
              BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
            ) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 80,
                  child: Image.asset("assets/Navigatu-icon.ico"),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                    String url = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['downloadURL'];
                    return SizedBox(
                      width: 80,
                      child: Image.network(url),
                    );
                  }),
                );
              }
            }),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 5),
              child: Text(
                name,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 5),
              child: Text(
                specialty,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontSize: 12,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is the Collection Tree in my firebase:
[Firebase Collection Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLqvb.png)

Here is the display I want to achieve. The boat picture here supposedly must be a Image.network, with the url that is in the sub-collection, named "Profile".
[Mentor Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7d1F.png)

As you can see in the code, I performed first the "final mentors", then performing streambuilder inside of it. So that I can get the datas of each document from the mother collection. Now I passed those data to the "mentorwidget" to display them in a proper way, but then I wanna use a Image.network, containing the data inside the sub-collection of each document in the mother collection. That's why I performed another streambuilder inside the mentorwidget to display the picture, or get the data of the sub-collection which is the url of the said picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I found the answer! thanks to Slender's answer, I managed to get the answer, here is the code.

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("mentors")
              .doc(uid)
              .collection("profile")
              .get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 80,
                  child: Image.asset("assets/Navigatu-icon.ico"),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // print(snapshot);
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 80,
                  child: Image.network(
                      "${snapshot.data!.docs[0]['downloadURL']}"),
                );
              }
            }
            // print(snapshot.data!.docs[0]['downloadURL']);
            return const SizedBox(
              width: 80,
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data doesn't get frequently updated or if you don't need to display the constant changes of it's value to the users then use *FutureBuilder* instead of *StreamBuilder* to query the value you want only once.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('mentors')
            .doc('b23lt...[your desired document ID]')
            .collection('Profile')
            .get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: , // lenght of snapshot data,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               //Here you can retrieve the data of each document
              },
            );
          }
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The code returns me this error.

RenderViewport#f2279 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Comment: If you have specified the *itemCount* property and get this issue just set the *shrinkWrap* property of ListView to **true**.

Comment: No good bro, still showing the error, and instead of showing the widget I returned, there is no display anymore. just plain blue bar without any writings inside.

Comment: I edited the question, hoped it'll help the experts more to understand that question. :(