# How to access collections inside the documents of another collection in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection A under which I have multiple documents. Every document has 2 collections in it: `subCollectionA` and `subCollectionB`.
I am currently able to access all the documents inside collection A as follows:

```
var _a = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('A').get();
for(int i=0; i<_a.docs.length; i++){
    // access _a.docs[i]
}
```

Is there a way to access the sub-collections inside these documents in flutter?

I tried to find the syntax for this, but I am unable to find it. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370286/display-sub-collection-in-flutter-firebase), but It's returning a widget and I would like to do these calculations per document in the above code before I display the widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read/query all `subCollectionA` collections, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). So:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('subCollectionA').get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I used `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("A").doc("doc").collection('subcollectionA').get()`